# How to use split method with string containing brackets?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a string that contains some data. Data is separated like this:

```
 var stringData = (SomeWordsWithSpacesInBetween) 0 (SomeWordsWithSpaceInBetween) 1 ...
```

I want to be able to extract data between the brackets and numbers between the words in brackets as such:

```
stringData.split( some way to split them)[0] = SomeWordsWithSpacesInBetween;
stringData.split(some way to split them)[1] = 0;
```

How to split them this way?

Comment: use [RegExp](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.4.0/dart-core/RegExp-class.html) class in `String.split()` method

Comment: @pskink, I know it's kinda lazy, but could you please help me understand how exactly it should be done?

Comment: so what is your problem actually? what is your `RegExp`?

Comment: @pskink, I found Regular expression as this - \((.*?)\) to find what's in the brackets, and excluding that regexp would find me numbers, right? So how to insert that in there?

Comment: `print(RegExp(r'\((.*?)\) \d+ ').allMatches('(foo bar) 0 (some text) 1 ').map((m) => m.group(1)));`

Comment: Thank you dude, only yours works normally after all, @pskink

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var s = '(Some Words With Spaces InBetween) 0 (SomeWordsWithSpaceInBetween) 1';
var r = RegExp(r'\(((\w+ ?)*)\) (\d+) ?').allMatches(s).expand((e) => [e[1], e[3]]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using regular expression. Here is an example.

```
List<String>getStringList(){

  String abc = '(SomeWordsWithSpacesInBetween) 0 (SomeWordsWithSpaceInBetween) 1 (SomeWordsWithSpaceInBetween)';
  List<String> myList = new List();
  RegExp exp = new RegExp(r"\) (\d+) \(");

  myList = abc.split(exp);
  print('${myList}');

  return myList;
}
```

Comment: I found this to be working on the words, but how to find the numbers in between?By the way thank you

Comment: RegExp exp = new RegExp(r"(\d+)");
  Iterable<RegExpMatch> x = exp.allMatches(abc);
  for(var y in x){
    print(y.group(0));
  }
@ZhangirSiranov